# Windows 8.1 Universal App References

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I have a windows 8.1 universal app. One part is desktop/tablet app and one is Windows phone.

I have been downloading all external libraries via nugget into the Windows 8.1 and now my Windows Phone doesn't recognize it.

How can i reference it all under one "umbrella" or point the Windows Phone reference folder towards references in windows 8.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly. you added some Nuget packages to the Windows project and you have code in your Shared project that uses them, so the app does not build for Windows Phone.

The solution is to add the same Nuget packages to your Windows Phone project.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what is happening! Windows 8.1 is running normally because in his folder are all the references (nugget packages e.g. newtonsoft) and In WP there are none. I tought maybe there is a way to point my WP reference folder towards Windows 8.1 since they are already downloaded :)

Comment: what if I need to add a reference to newtonsoft for a class in the shared folder?